# Python: random module with sum accumulator for odd numbers

Tags: python, random, dice, accumulator

Hello I'm trying to make a function including the random module that only accumulates the sum of odd rolls of n-dice, n-sided times. Sounds a little confusing but for example if I rolled 2-sided die 2 times and got 1 and 2, the result would be only 1 (since 2 is even). Here's what I have:

```
import random

def roll(sides, dice):
    y = 0
    for i in range(1, dice+1):
        if y%2 == 1:
            y = y + random.randrange(1, sides+1)
    return y
```

How can I get this to work? It never gets past the first if because it starts at y=0

Comment: Do you have a question for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the problem is that you add a random number before checking if it's odd or even in your `for` loop.

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
def roll(sides, times):
    final_sum = 0
    for i in range(times):
        randnum = random.randrange(sides)
        final_sum += randnum if randnum % 2 else 0
    return final_sum
```

Answer (score 1):

Count of odd rolls:

```
count([1 for i in xrange(num_of_rolls) if (random.randint(1, sides)) % 2])
```

Sum:

```
rolls = [random.randint(1, sides) for i in range(num_of_rolls)]
sum_of_odd = sum([roll for foll in rolls if roll % 2])
```

Not tested, but should work :)

Comment: first, you don't need the square braces; second, you're counting the odd rolls, not summing the results; third, you're counting even rolls, since die face numbers usually (and in the given example) start from 1...

Answer (score 1):

..you wanted the one-liner, this is the oneliner :)

```
sum(r for r in (random.randrange(1, sides+1) for i in xrange(dice)) if r % 2)
```

Anyways, to reply to the OP's question: the problem with your code is you're checking whether the sum so far is odd, not the current die roll... to do that, you should do like this:

```
import random

def roll(sides, dice):
    total = 0
    for i in range(dice):
        result = random.randrange(1, sides+1)
        if result % 2:
            y += result
    return y
```

Comment: first, you are ignoring the number of rolls, second, you are ignoring the number of sides and third, ummmmm, I don't know, there should be third :) Yes, randrange(1, sides) is generating values in [1; sides) interval, not [1; sides], so the last is excluded :)

Comment: @JOHN oops.. Never copy-n-paste stuff from the interpreter without prior checking :P

Answer (score 0):

Your code should assign the random value to another variable first. Then check if odd. Then add it.

```
import random

def roll(sides, dice):
    y = 0
    roll = random.randrange(1, sides+1)
    for i in range(1, dice+1):
        if roll%2 == 1:
            y = y + roll
    return y
```